# Having multiple columns under 1 if clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write query like below

```
select 

if drophip = 1 then
0 as a,
0 as b,
1 as c,
1 as d

else if drophip = 0 then
1 as a,
1 as b,
0 as c,
0 as d

end if; 

from tabl1;
```

its giving syntax error. Is there any way i can write the same?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

I suppose your drophip is `boolean` field.

### **Query**

```
select 
case
    when drophip = 1 then 0
    else 1
end as a,
case
    when drophip = 1 then 0
    else 1
end as b,
case
    when drophip = 1 then 1
    else 0
end as c,
case
    when drophip = 1 then 1
    else 0
end as d
from tabl1;
```

Comment: You need to remove the last comma after `end as d`. [**Here is the fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c904e/4)

Comment: can i write 1 case for all columns?

Comment: @Hacker: No, you can't